# IWD OPC payment name shows double

Tags: checkout, payment, ce-1.9.1.0, payment-methods

I'm running a Magento 1.9 store and have just installed the IWD One Page Checkout extension. Everything works fine except one little kink...

The payment method names show up double
example:

> payment with Visa => VisaVisa

Does anyone have an idea where I can find this little bug?

If I've forgot to add important info let me know and I'll elaborate...

[image: Screenshot]

Update:

We have reduced the conflict between IWD and MSP plugin (Multisafepay payments (plugin free for download)) however a solution has not been found.
Does someone that uses MSP have the same issue or a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your MultiSafePay plugin:

Go to `app/code/community/MultiSafepay/Msp/Helper/Data.php` and on line 38 you see:

```
if ($return == '') {
    $return = $paymentTitle;
}
```

Change it to:

```
if ($return == '') {
    //$return = $paymentTitle;
}
```

Which will comment out the returning of the payment title along with the `$_method` tag. This should fix your problem.

Soon MSP will release 2.1.2 as a new release which will also have this patch onboard.

Comment: Works perfect! To others with the same problem, don't forget to CACHE, INDEX and COMPILE! We forgot the compilation and spent stupid hours to find the glitch!